# How to change the Material Date & Time Picker background color in Android?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-datepicker, materialdatepicker

How to **change the Material Date & Time Picker background color** in Android? i found many solution default date & time picker not Material design

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the default color using:

```
    val datePicker =
        MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
            .setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_App_MaterialCalendar)
            .build()
```

with:

```
 <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialCalendar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <!-- just override the colors used in the default style -->
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/...</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

or if you want to change also the white background:

```
   <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialCalendar4" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/...</item>
    </style>
```

[image]