# Android MaterialDatePicker : How to change color of calendar

Tags: android, datepicker, calendar, material-design, themes

I am trying to change color using style code in XML.
I am not able to change the background color of the calendar.

In the image below I want to change white color area of right side to some custom color of my choice.

[image: Image showing white color, which I want to change]

Currently I am using following theme to change color on left side to blue, and some rounded corners.

```
 <!--Calendar-->
<style name="AppDatePicker" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_click</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearanceMediumComponent">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent
    </item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearance.App.MediumComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.MediumComponent">
    <item name="cornerSize">16dp</item>
</style>


    long today = MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds();

    // going back by a week
    long startDate = today - 604800000L;
    long endDate = today;

    // setting available days for a week only
    List<CalendarConstraints.DateValidator> validatorList = new ArrayList<>();
    validatorList.add(DateValidatorPointBackward.now());
    validatorList.add(DateValidatorPointForward.from(startDate));

    CalendarConstraints constraints = new CalendarConstraints.Builder()
            .setStart(startDate)
            .setEnd(endDate)
            .setOpenAt(today)
            .setValidator(CompositeDateValidator.allOf(validatorList))
            .build();

    MaterialDatePicker<Long> selectDate = MaterialDatePicker.Builder
            .datePicker()
            .setCalendarConstraints(constraints)
            .setTheme(R.style.AppDatePicker)
            .setSelection(sharedPref.getSelectedSyncDate())
            .setTitleText("SELECT DATE")
            .build();

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    selectDate.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "DATE_PICKER");
```

Comment: This example can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170874/how-to-change-datepickers-calendarviews-background-color-in-lollipop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66958999/how-to-change-the-material-date-time-picker-background-color-in-android

Comment: Yes @Khushbu, I got help from your link.

Comment: Can you post it as an answer, rather than a comment/link, so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe issue is over here

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialCalendar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
   <!-- just override the colors used in the default style -->
   <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/...</item>
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>
 </style>
```